# PHP - Fetching Zip File and processing its contents

Tags: php

My goal is to fetch a zip file from a third party web server, grab the CSV file contained within and iterate through the content putting it line by line into an array for further processing.

The file I am grabbing is around 2000 lines long.

This is currently what I have::

```
 $zip = URL_TO_FILE;
 $internal_file = 'zipped_file_name.csv';

 $ext = pathinfo($zip, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $ext);

 copy($zip, $temp);

 $file = file_get_contents("zip://$temp#$internal_file");
```

The above works but does not seem ideal. Normally I grab an unzipped CSV file and simply iterate through the content as so and chuck the contents into an array.

```
  while ( ($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false ) {
      if ( array(0 => null) !== $line ) {
          $result[] = $line;
       }
  }
```

I am not sure how to do the same thing with the additional step of grabbing the zipped content. Also - I only need the last 100 lines of the file, not all 2000 lines.

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. How do I only grab the last 100 lines?
3. How do I iterate through the content line by line to put it into an array?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After searching about I found the solution::

```
 foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $file) as $line){
      $result[] = $line;
 }
```

What this does is iterate through each line of the content retrieved from the file. After that, all I do is an array split to get the latest information::

```
$newArray = array_slice($result, 0, 10);
```

For those who don't wish to piece this together, here is the code in a single chunk::

```
$zip    = $object->getUrl();
$file   = '649.csv';
$ext    = pathinfo($zip, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$temp   = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $ext);

copy($zip, $temp);

$file = file_get_contents("zip://$temp#$file");
unlink($temp);

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $file) as $line)
{
    $result[] = $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fgetcsv` function expects file handle. So instead of `file_get_contents` use `fopen`:

```
$fh = fopen("zip://$temp#$internal_file", "r");

while( ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
    ...
}
```